# Is it allowed to delete a file or close a window which contains a written name of Hashem?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, modern-times

The English word with three letters, God. Is it allowed to close this window, for example?

What is the ruling regarding electronic documents, photos, etc. Can they be deleted from the hard drive or should there be a prayer or ceremony about disposing of them?

What do the modern poskim say? Does Shaimos apply here?

Comment: isn't this more likely an offshoot of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38558/do-jews-believe-that-gods-name-is-god/38559#38559 asking whether the English construct is a name of God which would then be subject to the halachot of electronic devices?

Comment: Rabbi Soloveitchik wrote GOD on the blackboard at the school in Boston and then erased it to show that the halacha of erasure did not apply to it. This was told to me by one of the students who had been in that class at that time.

Comment: Yes the q has an answer there but it was't marked as accepted, nor has provided any source, so I don't think it adequately answers this question.