# Using the name Allah

Tags: halacha, names, islam, arabic

When talking to a Muslim about God is ok to use the term Allah? (I personally can’t see any halachik problems, but there’s a lot I can’t see)

Comment: Practically [same question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38558/15571) (and further related/dupes there) different name.

Comment: Allâh means G-d in Arabic. Though I never heard of a Moslem calling G-d Hashem.

Comment: @TurkHill Allah = God, Hashem = God, Gut = God, Shang di = God (you get the point). And what does ‘God’ equal/mean? The only thing they all have in common is that none are *names* of God.

Comment: @Oliver I understand your first point but not your 2nd, namely that, “that none are names of G-d.” Do you mean that these pagan god names are not the same meaning as Hashem yet quote them all to mean Hashem?

Comment: @TurkHill On the contrary, I mean they’re basically synonyms for ‘Hashem’, just different languages.

Comment: @Oliver I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Having grown up in Egypt and knowing Arabic, I can tell you that Jews (like Muslims) freely use "Allah" in conversation to refer to God, although it is frequently replaced by "Rabbena" (Our Master).  God is usually addressed directly as "Ya Rabb" (O Master).

Comment: For reference, "Allah" was originally just "el ilah" ("the god"), then the two words were fused together to emphasize the unity of God.

Comment: If you speak with Jews from Islamic countries, they often say _inshallah_ instead of _beezrat Hashem._

Comment: "Ya Rabb" "Ya Allah" Also common in Israel. I Haven't seen a Rabbi banns it.

Answer (score 10):

Rambam calls God *Allah*, for example in Sefer Hamitzvos, Negative Commandment 5 (Kapach, p. 183), “Worshiping any other than Allah”.

> כל מא יעבד מן דון אללה
>
> כל מה שנעבד מבלעדי ה׳

Parenthetically, God was also referred to by other names in Judeo-Arabic. For example, at the beginning of the sixth *maamar* in Emunos Vedeos (Kapach, p. 193), R’ Saadia Gaon refers to God as *Rabana*.

> ערפנא רבנא תבארך ותעאלי
>
> הודיענו אלהינו יתברך ויתעלה

Furthermore, the modern Arabic phrase *inshallah*, which connotes ‘God willing’ is also used. For example in Sefer Hamitzvos (Kapach, p. 9):

> ואלאסתדלאל עליה אן שא אללה
>
> ולהביא ראיות עליו, אם רצה ה׳

Comment: I'd guess it's rabena rather than rabana, if we're to trust the testimony of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/98399/170

Comment: @msh210 yes, I was thinking that but must’ve been using my Aramaic glasses.

Answer (score 2):

[Rabbi Ovadia Abraham Somech](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%93%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%9A) nickname was "Abdallah (Worshiper of god) Somech".

[[image: The nickname printed in his book]]

Answer (score 2):

As an Arabic speaker I can assure you that saying “Allah” is like saying “God” in English.  I’ve never heard of a Halakhic issue raised by any of the gedolim.

Comment: Akiva in addition to my welcome on another question, and since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. See in particular the focus on sourcing your answers. Since the we don't know you personally, we don't know how much weigh your assertions alone carry. Again great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Ok, sorry just getting used to this!

Comment: No need to be sorry. I was also new one day :-> And I wrote the guide above to codify what I learned. The site can be quirky at times