# Saying God is Great in Arabic - is a Jew allowed?

Tags: halacha, words, theology, islam

We all know the "aqbar" phrase. Is it permissible for a Jew to say this phrase?

The assumption is that it is ok, because it commonly said that we are talking about the same Hashem. [This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/75284/31534) question is relevant.

I am not talking about anything more than just saying it as a one-off, maybe as a nice gesture to a Muslim friend. Obviously not discussing formalising this in any way.

Comment: The answer is yes: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98395/using-the-name-allah

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Pri Chadash (Yoreh Deah 19:6) discusses whether a Jew can say this after reciting the brachah on shechitah. He rules that it is prohibited to say this after the brachah because it is a hefsek between the brachah and the shechitah, but suggests ways to avoid this issue and allows saying it in those cases:

> דע שבמקומות הללו הבהמות של עכו"ם הכשרות לוקחן הישראל והטרפות נשארות
> לו לקצב עכו"ם למוכרם לעכו"ם ולפי דת הישמעאלים אינה נכשרת הבהמה להם אלא
> אם כן יאמר השוחט בשעת השחיטה אלל"ה וואכב"ר, שרוצה לומר א-ל כביר, והם
> מקפידים שלא יאמרו מלות הללו אלא סמוך לשחיטה מיד (באופן שגם אינו יכול
> לברך ברכת השחיטה עד אחר אמירת דברים אלו) [תיקון מקונטרס אחרון: באופן
> שאינו יכול לברך ברכת השחיטה אלא קודם אמירת דברים אלו וצריך להפסיק בין
> דברים אלו לתחלת השחיטה (כך צריך לומר ובדפוס נפל טעות סופר)], הדבר פשוט
> דזה הוי הפסק בין ברכה לשחיטה והמפסיק בזה טועה ואין תקנה לזה אלא שישחוט
> עוף מתחילה ויכוין לפטור כל מה ששוחט אחר כך בברכה שבירך על שחיטת עוף,
> או אחר שכבר התחיל לשחוט מקמי גמר הכשר שחיטה שיברך ברכת השחיטה

Note that the Simlah Chadashah (quoted in Darkei Teshuvah 19:53) even allows saying this after the brachah if there is no other choice:

> כ' בשמ"ח סעי' ח' דבמקומות שעכו"ם אינם מניחים לישראל לשחוט אם
> לא שיאמר קודם שחיטה ב' תיבות אלו אלל"ה וואכב"ר המבואר בש"ע לעיל סוף
> סי' ד' שראוי לבטל זה אם א"א לבטלו יש להשתדל לאומרם קודם ברכה ואם גם זה
> א"א נ"ל כיון דהישראל מכוין במלות אלו שהשחיטה היא לשם הקב"ה שהוא אל
> כביר שצונו לשחוט לא הוי הפסק דמדבר מעניני שחיטה היא וא"א בלא"ה אבל לא
> יאמר מלות אלו וישחוט ויברך בב"א דבעינן הברכה עובר לעשייתן עכ"ל

Answer (score -1):

The full Arabic phrase is Allah is Great and Mohammed is His prophet. You might have to modify your inflections to ensure that is obvious that the sentence ends after "great".

Comment: No.  "Allah is great(er)" is one line, and "There is no god but God and M... is His prophet" is another line.